# Search MySQL data using Google Maps v3 API

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a system/web app that will view resident info from the map. My problem is how can I search resident with inputted value('name','last name',etc...) from text field and displays all result in a marker (with infowindow content) in the map with a value like in the text field?

I use codeigniter-googlemaps-v3 API library and Google Maps V3 API. Any help, suggestions, ideas and sample codes is heavenly appreciated.

Comment: Can you capture the `click` event on a submit button next to your input tag, and send the search to a script via AJAX? Are you searching your own database rather than Google Maps?

Comment: That's what i though in the first place, but i don't know how can i get the search result value from the CodeIgniter/php, 'cuz i use the controller to display the marker in the map(Codeigniter-googlemaps-V3 API library).

yes, i'm searching my own data from mysql database, i store coordinates there with their information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you are stuck. Your controller will do the search in response to an AJAX request, and return results in JSON. You can then decode the JSON response in JavaScript and use map calls to plot the results.

Comment: ok2, let me be clear; when i get the result, would i do the ajax to display the marker with the info from the controller data?

Comment: That's not very clear at all, sorry! Summary: capture the click event on a "search" button (or get the change event on a text input button) so that the search is handled in JavaScript. This sends the string to your server via AJAX, where you will need to handle it using a server-side language (e.g. PHP). Here you will run the search in MySQL and return zero or more results. These results are encoded by PHP into JSON and sent in the reply. The JavaScript finally decodes this and uses GMap primitives the plot the data within.

Comment: You can do AJAX calls using raw JavaScript, or libraries like jQuery will make it pretty easy also.

Comment: ok2, its all clear to me now, thank you so much @hafler!

maybe you need to post some code snippet/s on how to do it to help others whose new on Google Maps v3 API, what do you think? :)

Comment: @hafler, can you post some links or example to the problem plz? tnx :)

Comment: I think it would be better if you gave it a go first. The question is rather broad, and the process of breaking it down into constituent parts will be very good practice for you. Good luck!

Comment: that sounds challenging, but i can't against your choice so, tnx so much for the help. I will post some code if i get this done, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703631/displaying-marker-with-latlong-json-data-in-biostall-google-maps-v3-api-library), all my codes are there on how I solve the problem. The codes are in AJAX and in Controller form.

Although it's not complete, since you'll see at the link that there is an additional problem. And I base the solution on [this link](http://biostall.com/loading-infowindow-content-using-ajax-with-google-maps-api).